# My login does not work when I put my laravel project into xampp

Tags: php, laravel, server, xampp

My app works jus fine when I run it in the serve that is provide by the command "phpartisan serve" but when I move it to xamp it shows me the home page, everything is fine until there, but when I log in it redirects me to "localhost" (in xampp that route shows info about php).

the route in xamp is: localhost/laravel/public

my route file when I log in:

```
Route::get('/staff', function () { return view('admin.index'); });
```

I don't get why redirects me to localhost.

Comment: well, have you configured [the redirection once login](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php#L21)?

Comment: Do I need to do that? why is working with the server that laravel give me?

Comment: What do you have in your `AuthController.php` for `$redirectsTo`?

Comment: Hi @JorgeIvanAguirre, since you setup the laravel in xampp by just placing it in the htdocs - i suppose, by reading your explanation - instead of make a proper virtualhost that points to laravel's public. the root site is not laravel, but xampp's welcome page.. hence the redirection..

Answer (score 0):

In your builtin LoginController.php put the following code:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request)
{
    return redirect('/your path here'); // Redirect after login
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities:

1. You have configured a virtual host and you can access your site using something like `http://mysite.local`, if it's true, everything must work fine.
2. You access your site through localhost, something like `http://localhost/laravelproject/public`, in this case you have to do what @Muhammad Rizwan said, use absolute path in redirect:

   `protected function authenticated(Request $request)
   {
       return redirect('http://localhost/laravelproject/public'); // Redirect after login
   }`

But I strongly recommend to use virtual host.